# Getting the value of a cell from a gridview into a variable

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

I have been trying  for a week to get the value of a cell in a gridview. I keep getting the error - Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
here is the code

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexCbanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gridview1 = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        MessageBox.Show("You selected " + gridview1.Cells[5].Text + ".");
    }

    protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 

        if (data.sQLConnection != null && data.sQLConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            data.closeDB();
        }

        data.strConnStr = strConnStr;
        data.openDB();
        //Uri myUri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
        strCmd = "Select * From tblInvoices_OpenQuarter WHERE ClientID = " + ddl1.SelectedValue + "And MemberID = " + (Session["CurrentMemberID"]).ToString();


        List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd);
        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();

        param1.ParameterName = "@clientID";
        param1.Value = ddl1.SelectedValue ?? (object)DBNull.Value;  //HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("ClientNo");
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

        ds = data.ReturnDataSet(strCmd, param1.ParameterName, param1.Value);
        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        bSource.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        int rc = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = strCmd;
        SqlDataSource3.DataBind();
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

I really hope that someone can help

Comment: `gridview1.Cells[5].Text` Why is there a 5 there

Comment: `e.NewSelectedIndex` has the position you want I'm guessing.. Your question is not specific

Comment: The 5 looks like it could be the problem.  Where exactly (what line number) is the exception happening?

Comment: As @Greggz pointed out with the [5]…. gridview1.cells[]array start with zero...gridview1.Cells[4] would be the fifth position.

Comment: I'm guessing `gridview1.cells[5].Text` is accidentally hardcoded and there is no 6th element of the array.

Comment: the 5 is the cell that holds the data in the row that I am querying.  The problem occurs in the row above that, gridview1.selectedrow   line 101.  It is saying that there is no rows in the gridview when in fact there is 2

Comment: @Bill Can you show your aspx code?

Comment: Ok Guys, thanks for you help but after 3 days of frustration I have worked it ovalue.ut.  I have to databind the gridview immediately before asking for the value or each tine I need to get the  value. Once again, thanks.